# Scriptaculous Effect.Grow() start from set size, not 0

Tags: javascript, dom, user-interface, scriptaculous

I have a div that appears if errors were encountered during a processing step. I have a 'More Info' link which, when clicked, I would like to expand and show specific errors encountered.

I thought I could use scriptaculous and the `Effect.Grow()` animation but this seems to always start from 0px x 0px and scale up.

Is it possible to start from the existing dimensions of my div and grow from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Effect.Grow` doesn't provide any start-size parameter indeed and always starts from the 0. So you probably would want to reconsider the use of `Grow` and choose something else.

I would suggest `Effect.Morph` for the job - you may achieve the same kind of effect with a lot less hassle.

Comment: Thanks, guess I should have looked at the documentation more thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

you can sourround it with a `div` wrapper, which has the fixed positioning via css,
also having the same width&height like the *to be grown*

execute the effect on the *to be grown* `div`